tor_android (a guardianproject's app) warning/errors. How crucial they are?
I try to run the demo app 'tor-android' from the guardianproject (https://github.com/guardianproject/tor-android/tree/master).
When I run it, as I see in 'adb logcat', there are dozens of log-messages which look like these:
12-31 10:25:07.466 27362 27362 W tor: type=1400 audit(0.0:379623): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[29298407]" dev="sockfs" ino=29298407 ioctlcmd=0x894b scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c164,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c164,c256,c512,c768 tclass=tcp_socket permissive=0 app=org.torproject.android.sample.
Are these messages just warnings or they are errors?
Obviously, these messages are related to the absence of permissions of the Tor library when it tries to do some 'ioctl' on some socket(?). But apart from that, they look very cryptic and give no clue on how to avoid them. What is more, that app seems working fine despite of these!
So, why we have these messages; What it means the 'untrusted_app' phrase in them? Is there any way to avoid those messages altogether?
PS. If I had some more guardianproject-specific-QA chat-room link, I would submit this question there... but apparently I don't have any.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The warning messages are related to SELinux policy restrictions on the app, and while they may not be critical, they can be avoided by adjusting the SELinux policies or running the app in permissive mode, but modifying SELinux settings may compromise security.

Thank you for your answer. I actually asked chatGPT the same question and had an answer similar to yours. Then I tried to find a way to adjust the SELinux settings (just for the fun of it) but unfortunately I didn't find a way on how to do it. Can you give me some hint on that, please?
